# CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM tensorflow gpu. looking for solution

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

Got problem while predicting. Earlier it worked, and nothing has been changed in conda environment. I'm not sure it is CUDA problem, because of:

```
   tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
```

got: UbuntU 18.04, tf-gpu==1.13.1 CUDA DRVIER VERSION 10.0
GPUGeForce RTX 2080 Ti

also input batch is not empty.

have no idea what, should I do. Below full Error log:

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened          CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
    2019-08-08 10:59:46.010315: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at cudnn_rnn_ops.cc:1224 : Unknown: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1225): 'cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor( tensor_desc.get(), data_type, sizeof(dims) / sizeof(dims[0]), dims, strides)'
2019-08-08 10:59:46.010454: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at cudnn_rnn_ops.cc:1224 : Unknown: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1225): 'cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor( tensor_desc.get(), data_type, sizeof(dims) / sizeof(dims[0]), dims, strides)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_test.py", line 61, in <module>
    input_term = deepspeech([row['path']])[0]
  File "/home/ai/dp_keras_model_cnn_extension/DeepSpeech-Keras/source/deepspeech.py", line 68, in __call__
    y_hat = self.predict(X)
  File "/home/ai/dp_keras_model_cnn_extension/DeepSpeech-Keras/source/deepspeech.py", line 104, in predict
    return self.distributed_model.predict_on_batch(X)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/voice-mvp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1274, in predict_on_batch
    outputs = self.predict_function(ins)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/voice-mvp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/home/ai/anaconda3/envs/voice-mvp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/home/ai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/ai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError:  CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
    in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1225):  'cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor( tensor_desc.get(), data_type, sizeof(dims) /   sizeof(dims[0]), dims, strides)'
     [[{{node replica_0/DeepSpeech/bidirectional_1/CudnnRNN_1}}]]
     [[{{node replica_1/DeepSpeech/time_distributed_2/Reshape_1}}]]
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?